# android , How could I make this code short using For loop

Tags: android

this is my code

```
LinearLayout ll[] = new LinearLayout [9];
ll[0]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay1);
ll[1]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay2);
ll[2]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay3);
ll[3]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay4);
ll[4]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay5);
ll[5]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay6);
ll[6]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay7);
ll[7]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay8);
ll[8]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay9);
ll[9]=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay10);
```

Comment: Do note the off-by-one error: your array has 9 elements, you're writing to 10.

Comment: Why would you want to? this is perfectly legible and very easy to quickly see what is happening. (obviously you will still want to fix the array size error). More verbose code doesn't have to always be a bad thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the ids into an array:

```
int[] ids = new int[] {R.id.rlay1, R.id.rlay2, R.id.rlay3, R.id.rlay4, R.id.rlay5,
     R.id.rlay6, R.id.rlay7, R.id.rlay8, R.id.rlay9, R.id.rlay10};
LinearLayout ll[] = new LinearLayout [10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ll[i] = (LinearLayout)findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

I prefer this solution over the use of `Resources.getIdentifier` since it does not cause resource id lookup costs at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your code:

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

Then change your code so:

```
LinearLayout ll[] = new LinearLayout [10];
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ll[i] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(getResourceID("rlay" + (i + 1), "id", ctx));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout ll[] = new LinearLayout [10];
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  int id = getResources().getIdentifier("rlay"+i, "id", getPackageName());
  ll[counter++] =  (LinearLayout)findViewById(id);
}
```